# Problems using Curl (56)

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services, curl

I am using AWS and Curl to send a request to a web service that connects to port 8080, I have already consumed another web service that connects to different ports and I have no problem, but with this, when I send the request, it quickly rejects the connection and The errno 56 code returns.

Is there a limitation in Curl that blocks connections when sending to a site with this port?

Comment: You are connecting to an AWS service? Can you provide more details on what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I am using an application hosted on AWS, the site to which I send the request only accepts IP in its whitelist in which I have already been included, I can access it from the console using curl -k, in my console and bypass the certificate validation since it is self-signed, but when sending the order it automatically denies me the connection and returns the code 56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The cURl error 56 can have different reasons like: Passing data to be uploaded in URL itself instead of POST request. Probably Proxy blocking the request to the server. In some cases, the server does not support particular request, like some servers support PUT/POST any one of them.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding the SOAPAction in my header